# How this type of GUI is made?

Tags: c, linux, user-interface, material-design

I want to design a GUI for my application which is written in C. I am very interested in material design.

I can implement material design gui using html css jQuery in browser, but how to make it native?

[For example this type of gui, this is not material design but its beautiful](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0FOkn.jpg)

I want to make this type of GUI in linux. Where should I begin?

I am currently using Fedora 24.

Comment: which case do you need this gui ? mobile interface ,web or desktop application?

Comment: @NiroshanRanapathi for desktop application

Answer (score 4):

Avast is using my HTMLayout for the UI. That is HTML/CSS UI engine for desktop applications. (2018 update: they use Sciter too now).

I've made next version of the engine named [Sciter](http://sciter.com/) that works on Windows, MacOS and Linux too. Check screenshots on the front page. These are all HTML/CSS Sciter UIs: Norton Antivirus, Bitdefender, Comodo, etc.

Comment: Can i use this for my personal college project, using the publicly available binary published on github?
Will that violate any license term?

Comment: Sure, it's free. Check its introductory article: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/859098/Sciter-multiplatform-embeddable-HTML-CSS-scripting

Comment: Another question that i have is that, i don't want to use c++, i want to use C only.
Will that be any problem?

Comment: Sciter uses plain C API.  The hole API is exposed as large structure with function pointers: https://github.com/c-smile/sciter-sdk/blob/master/include/sciter-x-api.h

Comment: @c_smile
 And can i use any css property or html5 tag i want?

Comment: Here is the list of supported CSS properties : http://sciter.com/docs/content/css/cssmap.html CSS2.1 + some CSS3 features.